# Why is there a pandas dataframe leak until I call values on the dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, memory-leaks

I have a situation where I have a very large pandas dataframe and much of the processing is done with data type float 16 due to memory constraints.  At a point in the process I save the current results to a cache, and the parquet format requires float 32 -- so I upcast at this point. (At this point my aggregated data can fit into memory.)

(for each float column, I do df[col] = df[col].astype('float32'))

The issue I'm having is that after I've converted all of the columns to float32; the amount of memory that has appeared to leak is exactly the size of the original float16 dataframe.  I can't figure out how to release it.

In my toying around; I did discover a way to produce a similar issue (though not exactly like mine)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1024**3))
df[0] = 1.0
df.values.flags
df[0] = df[0].astype('float16')
# too much memory being utilized until the next line is called
df.values.flags
```

If I omit df.values.flags the first time, the memory leak doesn't show up. If I insert it; the memory leak remains until I call it a second time.  I'm hoping knowing why this is happening will help me with my problem since it's very similar.